# POST and GET API Request using fetch, cannot get the data

Tags: javascript, api, fetch-api

i'm trying to use this website: https://rel.ink/,
to implement a link-shortener in my webapp,
i can successfully POST a request, but what i GET back is the same object, not a shortened version.
I know it's basic stuff but i can't wrap my head around it.
The website states that i need to send more information with my GET request, but the GET requests should not contain a body yes?

Here's my code:

```
async function fetchNewLink() {

  let newLinkJson = await postLink(input.value)

  let newLink = await getShortLink(newLinkJson)
  console.log(newLink)
}

function postLink(input) {
  return fetch('https://rel.ink/api/links/', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        url: input
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json"
      }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => json)
}

function getShortLink(response) {
  return fetch('https://rel.ink/api/links/' + response.hashid)
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then(newLink => newLink)
}
```

Many thanks

Comment: HTTP method `GET` must not have any `body`. If you need to pass data, data may be sent via HTTP parameters or HTTP headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you're trying to get is the shortened version of the link, the API does not return exactly that when you make a request. However, all you need is the `hashid` it returns. The shortened link is the main website's url(`https://rel.ink`) concatenated with the `hashid`.

So if the API returns `nJzb3n` as the `hashid` when you make a POST request, the shortened link would be `https://rel.ink/nJzb3n`

I hope that helps.

Comment: you are absolutely right, i managed to figure this out myself, i was trying to overthink it i guess. thanks anyway!

Comment: Oh okay. No problem.